# How to prove that $e = \lim_{n \to \infty} (\sqrt[n]{n})^{\pi(n)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n\#} $?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, definition

While reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96606/how-to-prove-limit-of-11-nn-e) post, I stumbled across these definitions ([Wiki_german](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulersche_Zahl))

$$e = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n\#}$$

and

$$e = \lim_{n \to \infty} (\sqrt[n]{n})^{\pi(n)}.$$

The last one seems interesting, since $ \lim_{n \to \infty} (\sqrt[n]{n})=1$, proven
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28348/proof-that-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-sqrtnn-1).

How to prove these?

Comment: In the second one, you can use that $\pi(n)\sim n/\log(n)$ asymptotically.

Comment: Regarding your comment, note that $\pi(n)\to\infty$, so in order for $\sqrt[n]{n}^{\pi(n)}$ to have a finite limit it is necessary for $\sqrt[n]{n}$ to converge to $1$.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: So infact one doesn't really need $\pi(n)$ to prove it?

Comment: Let's just say that it is an awkward way to rephrase a property of the [prime-counting function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function). Same is probably true for the primoral $n\#$.

Comment: Definitions? Of what are those two formulas "definitions"? Anyway, the product of the primes up to $n$ is asymptotic to $e^n$ - I believe this is at the same level of difficulty as the Prime Number Theorem - that should get you the first equation.