# Find $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}$

Tags: limits

Find the limit for $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}$

I have no idea how to do this - they always say use the ratio test when there are factorials but the nth root stuff makes it so ugly and i can't get anything to come out of it. Does anyone know what process I should use?

Comment: Are you dealing with a sequence or a series?

Comment: Ratio test is for series, not sequences.

Comment: sequence - I shall change title

Comment: The title is right, you just mention the ratio test, which is not much use for sequences (except that for a sequence to converge to a nonzero value, you must have $x_{n+1}/x_n\to 1$.)

Comment: So what do you suggest as an alternative? :(

Comment: Alternative: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/201906/9464

Comment: @vadim123 Is the equivalent enough here? I haven't worked out the details using Sitrling's, but the fact that a $n$-th root is taken gives me the gut feeling that more terms in the expansion are needed. (?)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/28476/9464

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/321892/9464

Answer (score 2):

**Result:** If $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}}=l$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\sqrt[n]{a_n}}=l$

Take $(a_n)^{1/n}=\left(\frac{n^n}{n!}\right)^{1/n}$ Now consider $a_n=\frac{n^n}{n!}$ and $a_{n+1}=\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$.

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e$$ hence $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}=e$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_n = \frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}$

$\log(x_n) = \log(n) - \dfrac{\log(n!)}{n} = \dfrac{n\log(n) - \sum_{k=1}^n \log(k)}{n}$

by [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem), it has the same limit as $(n+1)\log(n+1) - \log(n+1) - n\log(n) = \log\left((1+\dfrac{1}{n})^n\right) \to \log(e) = 1$

Comment: @ClementC. $\log(x_n)$ conveges to 1, which means $x_n$ converges to $e$

Comment: You're right, I had misread what you had done (forgetting the $\log$).

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
\frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}=\left(\frac{n^n}{n!}\right)^{1/n}=\exp\left(\frac1n\,\log\left(\frac{n^n}{n!}\right)\right)
=\exp\left(\frac1n\,n\log n-\frac1n\,\log n!\right)
=\exp\left(\log n-\frac1n\,\sum_{k=2}^n\log k\right).
$$
Now we have
$$
\int_1^{n-1}\log t\,dt\leq\sum_{k=2}^n\log k\leq\int_1^n\log t\,dt,
$$
i.e.
$$(n-1)\log n-(n-2)\leq\sum_{k=2}^n\log k\leq n\log n - (n-1).$$
Then
$$\log n-\log n+\frac{n-1}n\leq\log n-\frac1n\,\sum_{k=2}^n\log k\leq\log n-\frac{n-1}n\,\log n+\frac{n-2}n,$$
or
$$1-\frac{1}n\leq\log n-\frac1n\,\sum_{k=2}^n\log k\leq-\frac{1}n\,\log n+1-\frac2n.$$
Thus
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\log n-\frac1n\,\sum_{k=2}^n\log k=1,
$$
and
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(\log n-\frac1n\,\sum_{k=2}^n\log k\right)\\ &=\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\log n-\frac1n\,\sum_{k=2}^n\log k\right)\\ &=\exp(1)=e.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Using an asymptotic expansion of $\ln(n!)$, obtained e.g. as in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1489770/proving-asymptotic-barrier-o-notation/1489796#1489796) (there, by a comparison series/integral):
$$\ln(n!) \operatorname*{=}_{n\to\infty} n\ln n - n +o(n)$$
you get
$$
\sqrt[n]{n!} = e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln(n!)} = e^{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \ln k} = e^{\frac{1}{n}\left( n\ln n - n + o(n)\right)}
=
e^{\ln n - 1 + o(1)} = n\cdot e^{-1+o(1)}
$$
and therefore
$$
\frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}} = e^{1+o(1)} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} e.
$$