# How can we solve $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left (1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n$?

Tags: limits, exponential-function, indeterminate-forms

Taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)):

> The number $e$ is the limit $$e = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left (1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n$$

**Graph of $f(x) = \left (1 + \dfrac{1}{x} \right)^x$** [taken from here.](http://www.meta-calculator.com/online/paw750g2nx4z)

[image: Graph]

Its evident from the graph that the limit actually approaches $e$ as $x$ approaches $\infty$. So I tried approaching the value algebraically. My attempt:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left (1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n$$
$$= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n + 1}{n}\right)^n$$
$$= \left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n + 1}{n}\right) \right)^n$$
$$= 1^\infty$$

which is an indeterminate form. I cannot think of any other algebraic manipulation. My question is that **how can I solve this limit algebraically?**

Comment: It depends on your definition of $e$.

Comment: Usually, we prove that the sequence given by $a_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ is increasing and bounded, hence convergent, and just call $e$ its limit. With this assumption, there is nothing to prove.

Comment: Perhaps have a look at [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96606/how-to-prove-lim-n-to-infty-11-nn-e) and other questions [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/96606)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An algebraic way is Binomial Expansion, which is given by
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\!n} &=& 1+n\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\!2}+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\!3}+\cdots \\ \\
&=& 1+1+\frac{n(n-1)}{n^2}\cdot\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{n^3}\cdot \frac{1}{3!}+\cdots \\ \\
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Now every term in front there goes to $1$ for $n\to \infty$, so that the limit gives 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\!n} = 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + \cdots = \mathrm{e}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that

$$\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n=e^{n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}$$

Can you solve the limit now?

Comment: It appears strange to me. Do we need to use $e$ to find the value of $e$?

Comment: I don't know any way of solving it without prior knowledge of $e$. Maybe the other answer is more satisfying!

Comment: @unknownCoder not really. You can write $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n = 2^{n \log_2(1+1/n)}$, and you'll have to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} n \log_2(1+1/n) =  1/\ln(2)$, i.e. that the derivative of $\log_2(1+x)$ is $\frac{1 / \ln(2)}{1+x}$

Comment: @unknownCoder  note this is a definition of $e$ : $\log_a' (x) = \frac{f(a)}{x}$ where $1/f(a)$ is a logarithm in some base that we'll call $e$, such that $\log_e'(x) = \frac{1}{x}$