# Is it possible to write every integer with only one $3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, puzzle

There's a cool math challenge about [writing every number from 0 to 100 with exactly three $3$'s](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/funny/3_3.shtml).

Most of the solutions use a clever way to write $50$ with only one $3$ :

$$ \left \lfloor\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{3!!!}}}}}}}}}}\right \rfloor = 50 $$

I wonder if it's possible to write every natural number with a similar way ?

Edit : To keep the spirit of the puzzle, I think only factorials, square roots and floor functions are allowed.

Comment: I'm not sure what is says about humanity that we have time for pursuits like this.  I guess a testament to how easy life has become.

Comment: You'll need to define what "base operations" are ok.  Otherwise, you could just let $S:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ be the successor function, and write $n$ as $S^{n-3}(3)$ where $S^n(k)$ is the $n$th iterate of $S$.  If you don't like the $n-3$ in the "exponent", you could similarly write $S(S^{n-4}(3))$, and you've done it via a single 3.

Comment: @Mark You're right, I should clarify. To keep the spirit of the puzzle, I think only factorials, square roots and floor functions should be allowed.

Comment: Probably.  See this related question (with 4 instead of 3): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48633/using-floor-ceiling-square-root-and-factorial-functions-to-get-integers

Comment: Because you could continue using factorials, square roots, or floors indefinitely, I see no reason why you would not be successful.