# problem about number and power of 2

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Starting digits of 2^n](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13131/starting-digits-of-2n)

can anyone give me a hint ?

Prove that any finite sequence of digits is a starting sequence of digits for some power of $2$.

This is my attempt :
suppose the random finite sequence is $a_1a_2...a_i = A_i$ (its decimal value)
need to prove that for every $A_i$ there exist $b_1b_2...b_i = B_i$ and $n$ such that $A_iB_i = 2^n$
or $A_i\times 10^k + B_i = 2^n$ ( $k$ is number of digits in $B_i$)
we need $0 < Bi < 10^k$
the problem becomes, prove that for every $A_i$, there exist $n$ and $k$ such that 
$Ai\times 10^k < 2^n < A_{i+1}\times 10^k$.
I'm still working on it...
perhaps give me a hint on how to prove this or maybe there's a better way

Comment: You could use the Weyl Equidistribution Theorem: If $\alpha$ is irrational, then the set $\{[n\alpha] : n\in\Bbb N\}$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$.

Comment: sorry i haven't learnt that theorem, the solution will definitely not involve such theorem. Unless, its proof is really simple

Comment: oh isee i will look it up