# using kronecker's theorem can we prove there's some power of two yielding a number whose initial digits equal my social security number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion, diophantine-approximation

I just watched the "Great Courses" series of lectures in number theory, in which Professor Burger stated that

*using [Kronecker's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_theorem)*

> for any irrational number r, the sequence ({n * r})  where n >= 0 is
>   dense in the interval [0,1)

*we can prove there's some power of two yielding a number whose initial digits equal my social security number.*

The sketch of the proof given in the course used the fact that  log 2  is an irrational number. I tried to flesh out the whole proof to really understand it and I got stuck.

**My attempt at a proof**

First assume my social security number is 566...

From Kronecker:

there exists m |   m * log 2   =    X.566...

Since log 2^x  =   x * log 2, we have

```
m * log 2   =    X.566...
log 2 ^ m = X.566...
```

What to do next?  Or maybe I need to start on a different 
tack ? I'd be very grateful for any tips or guidance.

( kroenecker proof details [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=co5rCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA534&lpg=PA534&dq=kronecker%27s%20theorem%20dense%20in%20the%20real%20numbers%20in%20the%20interval%200%20to%201&source=bl&ots=T9RYzbTP2M&sig=xvhWqbRmWhm39dgJ_XJK3zMrvNE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAWoVChMIss_-i97vxgIVyEGICh0ZzQfr#v=onepage&q=kronecker's%20theorem%20dense%20in%20the%20real%20numbers%20in%20the%20interval%200%20to%201&f=false) )

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/131281/11619), or, for an even earlier incarnation of this question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/13131/11619).

Comment: $\lg 5.66\approx 0.752816$ and $\lg 5.67\approx0.753583$, so you want an integer $n$ such that $X.75282\le n\lg2\le X.75358$ for some integer $X$.

Comment: The answer could depend on the rest of your SSN, you better post the remaining digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N$ be the integer formed out of the required digits (for instance, your SSN).  We want the first digits of $2^n$ to line up with those of $N$.  Verify for yourself that it is equivalent to check that there exists a (non-negative) integer $k$ such that
$$
10^k \cdot N \leq 2^n \leq  10^k \cdot (N + 1)
$$
Taking the log base $10$ of all of these, we see that $n$ is the exponent we want if there exists an integer $k$ such that we have the inequalities
$$
k + \log_{10} N \leq n \log_{10}2 \leq  k + \log_{10}(N + 1)
$$
Perhaps now you can relate what you're looking for to Kronecker's theorem.

Comment: i understood the two steps that you wrote down.. but still not seeing how i can  relate this to Kronecker.   But i understand a bit better than before.. so thanks !   I will keep thinking about it till it (hopefully) sinks in.

Comment: You need to show that the condition that I wrote here amounts to checking that $$\{\log_{10}(N)\}\leq \{\log_{10}(2)n\} \leq \{\log_{10}(N+1)\}$$

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting close to wrapping my head around it.  I think what you are getting at in the comment above is that the fractional  parts of the two bounds "log-base-10(N)" and "log-base-10(N+1)" are two points along the interval [0,1).  by kroenecker, there exists a multiple M of (irrational) log-base10(2) for which the fractional part of M    falls within that interval.   So let's say M is comprised of an integer part "I" and  a fractional part "F".  Then  M = I.F (where I and F are strings of digits).  Then we can recover the "k"  in your first two equalities by setting k = I

Comment: Yep! ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: woo hoo !   this was a fun one.. thanks!