# For any $n$ is there $n$ consecutive $0$ in the decimal expansion of $2^m$ for suitable $m \in \mathbb N$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

We have define a function $f:\mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N$ such that $f(n)=$ { smallest $m \in \mathbb N$ such that decimal expansion of $2^m$ have $n$ consecutive $0$ }.
I computed some values of $f$:
$f(1)=10$  $\quad 2^{10}=1024$  have $1$ consecutive $0$.
$f(2)=53$ $\quad 2^{53}=9007199254740992$  have $2$ consecutive $0$...
$f(3)=242$
$f(4)=377$
$f(5)=1491$
$f(6)=1492$
$f(7)=6801$
$f(8)=14007$
.
.
.
Is it true that $f$ is a well defined function?!

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13131/starting-digits-of-2n).

Comment: Just a pretty obvious comment, but you could rephrase your question as to whether for each $n$, you can find a power $2^m$  that has $n$ or more consecutive 0's in the expansion of $2^m$. The minimality condition in your definition automatically follows.

Comment: @DavidMitra You basically knocked the question out of the park. In my opinion you should post as an answer, with the quick reasoning to make the desired deduction here.

Comment: @user2566092: It's possible $ \{ $smallest $m \in \mathbb N$ such that decimal expansion of $2^m$ have $n$ consecutive $0\}= \phi$ !

Comment: @2000 The post has that obvious error. Regardless, it holds for any "decimal digits" with a non-zero first digit. [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544214/is-2k-2013-for-some-k) is a related post that gives more detail for a specific case.

Comment: @DavidMitra : O! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Since $\log_{10}(2)$ is irrational, you can use [Weyl's equidistribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem) or [Dirichlet's approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem) to prove your result.