# Given $n$, exist $k$ such that $2^k$ contains $n$ as string.

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, open-problem

I have this doubt:

> Given $n\in \mathbb{N}$, does exist $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $2^k$ contains $n$ as a string in it?

For example, $53$ is in $2^{16}=65\color{red}{53}6$.

I just thought the problem right now so I don't have knowledge if it's even possible to solve it, but sounds a very nice problem. Does someone has an idea?

Comment: See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2230226/show-that-there-are-infinitely-many-powers-of-two-starting-with-the-digit-7) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544214/is-2k-2013-for-some-k).

Comment: https://oeis.org/A030000 is worth a look.

Comment: @Arthur:  that question asked for the string to start $2^n$, while here we are permitted to have it in the middle.  Still, that one solves the problem.