# On the appearance of an infinite number of prime numbers in the sequence $2^n$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

> Is it true that there is an infinite number of prime numbers $p$ for which there exists at least one natural number $m_p$ such that $p$ is contained in the decimal expansion of $2^{m_p}$?

To clarify what I exactly mean, let us take as an example $p=19$. Then we can take $m_p=13$ because $2^{13}=8192$ and we see that $p=19$ is contained in the decimal expansion of $2^{13}$.

Comment: Yes. It's implied by the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/13131/420432)

Comment: @nickgard:  that question is even stronger.  It shows that every prime is so contained, not just an infinite number of primes.