# Digits in exponentents including all digits 0-9

Tags: number-theory

Is it true that for all integers $k = 1, 2, 3, \cdots$ except powers of 10 ($1, 10, 100, \cdots, {10}^n, \cdots$),

there exist an integer $n$ such that $n^k$ include all digits from 0-9?

Example:

$$2 ^ {68} = 295147905179352825856\\
3 ^ {39} = 4052555153018976267\\
5 ^ {19} = 19073486328125$$

I can't seem to make any progress on this question, other than that if $n^{ab}$ includes all digits, then so must $(n^a)^b=(n^b)^a$... That's trivial though

Thank you

Comment: If $n$ is such that $\log_{10}n$ is irrational then there is a power of $n$ that starts with any given string of numbers.  I'll look up a proof for the $n=2$ case...

Comment: @lulu Ah , yes, you are right. That is the proof :)

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13131/starting-digits-of-2n) is a proof for $n=2$.  The general case I mentioned is no different.

Comment: A much stronger claim, which is much harder to prove, is that for each base $n$ only finitely many $k$ are such that $n^k$ does not have all the digits.  As $k$ gets large, $n^k$ has lots of digits and it is hard to avoid any of them.  http://oeis.org/A007377 gives the powers of $2$ that do not have a $0$ and states the conjecture that $86$ is the last.

Comment: @RossMillikan  Are you saying that a proof of that is known?  Certainly a natural conjecture...

Comment: @lulu:  no, I do not believe it has been proven.  The OEIS sequence says it is only a conjecture that $86$ is the last for $2$.  But when you get to trillions of digits, how can you miss?

Comment: @RossMillikan  Oh, I agree that a counterexample would be astonishing. And even the "$86$" seems like a stretch, but I thought that maybe finiteness was doable.   Not that I have the slightest idea how to attack it.

Comment: @lulu:  I'm sure the search has been run a long ways.

Comment: @RossMillikan: The OEIS entry says it's been checked up to $2^n$ for $n=10^{10}$.

Comment: @lulu: We should expect

$$\frac{\log_210\cdot0.9^{n/\log_210}}{1-0.9}\approx33.2\cdot0.9^{n/3.32}$$ counterexamples for exponents above $n$. So $86$ is actually a bit lower than expected, since above that about $33.2\cdot0.9^{86/3.32}\approx2.2$ counterexamples would have been expected.